# Flask reload only a specific template and not the full page

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to reload only a specific template, but instead, the full page is reloaded:
[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVc6E.png)

There are 4 templates: main.html - form.html - home.html - result.html

And after clic on button Calc I want to load only the result.html and not the full page.

main.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
        <!-- <title>{{ titulo }}</title> -->
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="div_principal">   
            {% include "form.html" %}
            
            {% if route == '/' %}
                {% include "home.html" %}
            {% endif %}

            {% if route == '/results' %}
                {% include "results.html" %}
            {% endif %}

            <form action="{{ url_for('home') }}"> 
                <button type="submit" class="button" id="home" >Home</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

form.html

```
<form class="form" id="form" action="{{ url_for('calc') }}" method="post"> 
    <div>
      <label for="field_a" onclick="msgRazEq()">A</label>
      <input type="number" id="field_a" name="field_a" class="input_number" value="{{ request.form['field_a'] }}" step="0.01" min="0.00" required>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="field_b" onclick="msgRazEq()">B</label>
      <input type="number" id="field_b" name="field_b" class="input_number" value="{{ request.form['field_b'] }}" step="0.01" min="0.00" required>
    </div>
  <button type="submit" class="button" id="calc">Calc</button>
</form>
```

home.html

```
<h1>HOME</h1>
```

results.html

```
<h1>{{ result }}</h1>
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "ASDASDFASDFASDF"

from views.views import *


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=8086, host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, threaded=True)
```

views.py

```
from flask import render_template, request, redirect, url_for, session
from app import app

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('main.html', route = "/")

@app.route('/calc', methods=["POST",])
def calc():
    a = eval(request.form['field_a'])
    b = eval(request.form['field_b'])
    c = a * b
    session['c'] = c
    return redirect(url_for('results'))

@app.route('/results')
def results():
    result = session.get('c', None)
    return render_template('main.html', route = "/results", result = result)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to reload the entire page, but just replace a part, I advise you to use AJAX.

The submit event of the form is intercepted with JavaScript and the standard behavior of the form is suppressed. The data is then sent to the server via [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) and the result obtained is inserted into the page as text.

###### Flask (app.py)

```py
from decimal import *
from flask import (
    Flask, 
    render_template, 
    request
)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.post('/calc')
def calc():
    a = request.form.get('field_a', 0, type=Decimal)
    b = request.form.get('field_b', 0, type=Decimal)
    c = a * b
    return render_template('results.html', **locals())
```

###### HTML (templates/index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form name="form"> 
        <div>
            <label for="field_a">A</label>
            <input type="number" id="field_a" name="field_a" value="0" step="0.01" min="0.00" required>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="field_b">B</label>
            <input type="number" id="field_b" name="field_b" value="0" step="0.01" min="0.00" required>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="button" id="calc">Calc</button>
    </form>

    <div id="results"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function(uri) {
            const elem = document.getElementById('results');
            const form = document.querySelector('form[name="form"]');
            form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                const formData = new FormData(this);
                fetch(uri, {
                    method: 'post', 
                    body: formData
                }).then(resp => resp.ok && resp.text())
                  .then(text => { elem.innerHTML = text; });
            });
        })({{ url_for('calc') | tojson }});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

###### HTML (templates/results.html)

```
<h1>{{ c }}</h1>
```

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

because you did not tell jinji2  include the form.html only if the route is /
so i hope this help u

instead of

```
<body>
    <div class="div_principal">   
        {% include "form.html" %}
        
        {% if route == '/' %}
            {% include "home.html" %}
        {% endif %}

        {% if route == '/results' %}
            {% include "results.html" %}
        {% endif %}

        <form action="{{ url_for('home') }}"> 
            <button type="submit" class="button" id="home" >Home</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

to that

```
<body>
    <div class="div_principal">   
        {% include "form.html" %}
        
        {% if route == '/' %}
            
            {% include "home.html" %}
            {% include "form.html" %}
        {% endif %}

        {% if route == '/results' %}
            {% include "results.html" %}
        {% endif %}


    </div>
</body>
```